# QFileDialog in c++: "no matching function for call"

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qfiledialog

I want to let the user choose a folder so I can display and sort its contents somewhere else. The best way to do this seems to be using `QFileDialog`. Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
> #include <QFileDialog>
.....
void someEvent(){
QString path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectoryUrl(this, tr("Choose a Folder"), QDir::home());
}
```

When I try to compile this I get the error:
no matching function for call to `QFileDialog::getExistingDirectoryUrl(MainWindow*, QString, QDir) path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectoryUrl(this, tr("Choose a Folder"), QDir::home());`

Note: I'm running Fedora 25 on this PC and I'm wondering whether that might be the issue?

Comment: The third parameter should be a `QUrl` (according to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectoryUrl)), but you are passing a `QDir`

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use [`getExistingDirectory`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) with `QDir::home().path()` as third parameter?

Comment: Or `QDir::homePath()` http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#homePath

Comment: I used  `getExistingDirectory ` with `QDir::home().path()` as the third parameter and it worked. Thanks @UnholySheep , @drescherjm and @PerryC !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 choices depending on your needs, the first one being the best :

[getExistingDirectory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) :

```
QString path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,tr("Choose a Folder"),QDir::homePath());
```

[getExistingDirectoryUrl](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectoryUrl) :

```
QUrl url = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectoryUrl(this,tr("Choose a Folder"),QUrl(QDir::homePath()));
QString path = url.toString();
```